# Excel VBA setting cursor position in table row after adding and sorting

Tags: excel, vba

Pressing the Add button will add a row to a table and fill it with information held in the named ranges _FoodType and _FoodItem.  Then it sorts the table.  Now I would like to make the current selection the row I just added.  Is there a way to do this without having to search for my item after the sort? (image reflects how it looks after Add code is run.  I want it to highlight the Brownie row)

[image]

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim tbl As ListObject
  Dim AddRow As ListRow
        
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Set rAddrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
     
    rAdd.Range(1, 1) = ws.Range("_FoodType").Value
    rAdd.Range(1, 2) = ws.Range("_FoodItem").Value
    
    tbl.Sort.SortFields.Clear
            
    tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("Table1[Food Type]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
               
    tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("Table1[Food Item]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    tbl.Sort.Apply
    
    '*********************select the row that was just added here:
    rAdd.Range.Select
    
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set tbl = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround.

Works if you don't have comments in the table.

Add a comment to the cell, search for it, then delete it.

Side note: You have some undeclared variables.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rAddRow As ListRow
        
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Set rAddRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    
    rAddRow.Range(1, 1) = ws.Range("_FoodType").Value
    rAddRow.Range(1, 2) = ws.Range("_FoodItem").Value
    rAddRow.Range(1, 2).AddComment "Look"
    
    tbl.Sort.SortFields.Clear
            
    tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("Table1[Food Type]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
               
    tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("Table1[Food Item]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    tbl.Sort.Apply
    
    '*********************select the row that was just added here:
    Dim addedRow As Range
    Set addedRow = Intersect(tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments).EntireRow, tbl.DataBodyRange)
    addedRow.Select
    
    addedRow.ClearComments
    
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set tbl = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

If you do have comments, the approach would be to add some unique text to the comment and then loop and search for it.

Let me know if it works